# Selecting links which has some specific hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select  elements (add active class) to links, which have previously selected hash.

So, i want to click at:

```
<a href="example.com/#about">
```

Then, page will show #about section, so all links with #about hash should have .active class.

This code below get hash from url, so only problem now is to find all links, and add active class:

```
$('header a').on('click', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        alert (hash);
})
```

Comment: why are you fetching hash from the window's URL on clicking a link?

Comment: Because i may have a lot on links, so clicking on link, and then checking what user click looks like good solution...

Comment: It doesn't make sense, window.location returns current url. If you want to have anchor href in event handler you have to use this.href

Comment: have you got any example of better solution Maciej? Dzięki !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ends with `$` attribute selector to get the anchor tags.

```
$('header a[href$="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass('active');
```